# How to move a sprite across a gridLayout?

Tags: java

My goal is to have a sprite move across a gridLayout with arrow keys. So far, I haven't been successful with this. I don't know if I should be using the JPanel itself or use a JLabel for the images. When I try to move the sprite, the actual sprite doesn't move but the curX value continues to decrement(moving up). 
Here is the relevant code

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

private JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, GAP, GAP));    
private JPanel[][] panel = new JPanel[ROWS][COLS];
private JLabel label[][] = new JLabel[ROWS][COLS];

ImageIcon pea = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Downloads\\peaShooter.png");
ImageIcon sun = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Downloads\\sunflower.png");
ImageIcon rock = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Downloads\\rock.png");
ImageIcon zombie = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Downloads\\zombie.png");

JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel();
JLabel imgLabel2 = new JLabel();
JLabel imgLabel3 = new JLabel();
JLabel imgLabel4 = new JLabel();

}

public NewClass() {
Image transformed = pea.getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
Image transformed2 = sun.getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
Image transformed3 = rock.getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
Image transformed4 = zombie.getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

imgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(transformed));
imgLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(transformed2));
imgLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(transformed3));
imgLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(transformed4));

add(imgLabel);
add(imgLabel2);
add(imgLabel3);
add(pane);
addKeyListener(this);
panel[curX][curY].add(imgLabel);
}

    @Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    int keyCode = ke.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        panel[curX-1][curY].add(imgLabel);
        curX--;
    }
```

How would I make it so that when I press up the sprite is removed from its current position and re-added to its new position? I've tried using the JLabel added over the JPanel but it did not work (or I did something wrong).

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation of add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) it states "If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component."

My experience with java awt is limited but by calling `panel[curX-1][curY].validate();` after you add the image should be able to see your image.